# How should I implement api versioning in Apigee?

Tags: apigee

I'm pretty new to Apigee so apologies in advanced. We currently have an api which is accessed an Apigee proxy. From reading the Apigee best practices it looks like we should version the api in the URL like so

> api/v1/endpoint/

How do I go about stripping the version out of the URL and using it to target the correct api?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Rather than answering this with more theoretical content - I would suggest you try out the first sample - [Add and configure your first API](http://apigee.com/docs/api-services/content/add-and-configure-your-first-api) and you will be on your way to build your production API with good grip on how to use Apigee.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I go about stripping the version out of the URL and using it to target the correct api?

If you choose your base path to be "api/v1/endpoint/" like so:

```
<HTTPProxyConnection>
    <BasePath>/api/v1/endpoint</BasePath>
    <VirtualHost>default</VirtualHost>
</HTTPProxyConnection>
```

then only the part of the URL *after* /api/v1/endpoint will be sent to the target.  In this way, you avoid passing along the version portion of the URL to your target.